# t4 template linq issue

Tags: linq, templates, t4

How can I use Linq in a T4 template

This is my software environment information
vs2012
.net version 4.0

This is t4 template:

```
<#@ templatedebug="true" hostSpecific="true" #> 
<#@ output extension=".cs" #> 
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Core.dll" #> 
<#@ import namespace="System" #> 
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
```

When I call engine.ProcessTemplate(inputTemplate, host), it returns the contents of
`ErrorGeneratingOutput`. Why is that?

Comment: Is that the entire .tt file or just the header?

Comment: It means that an error happend during the generation...

Comment: are you sure the error is with your linq usage? This output just means some exception was thrown during generation...

Answer (score 4):

Old question I know, but I've just found the same thing.

When you reference `System.Core`, don't include `.dll`:

```
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
```

Comment: @jiangmin, it'd be nice if this got marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the error in the errors window of visual studio to see more information.

Also you can right click the .tt file and say debug template.